# Oracle AQ load test with Gatling

Tags: oracle, jms, performance-testing, gatling

I want to set up a Gatling testcase to put messages on a Oracle AQ. But I have no idea how to set up the the following:

```
val jmsConfig = jms
    .connectionFactoryName(???)
    .url("tcp://localhost:10002")
    .credentials("user", "secret")
    .contextFactory(???)
    .listenerCount(1)
    .usePersistentDeliveryMode
```

What is the connection factory name and what is the context factory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working using the *oracle.jms.AQjmsInitialContextFactory.* The above mentioned *oracle.jms.AQjmsFactory* is not an InitialContextFactory so that wont work.

Make sure to add at least version 11+ of the Oracle AQ dependencies for the AQjmsInitialContextFactory to be found.

You database user should of-course have the correct privileges to be able to insert messages into the queue (table).

Gatling expects your to have request-reply semantics, so it will wait for a reply to be received. I actually wanted to abort waiting for a reply after a specified period, but I have no clue how to do that. So if anyone know how to.. please tell me :-)

**MySimulation.scala**

```
val jmsConfig = jms
    .connectionFactoryName("ConnectionFactory") // MUST!!!! be called ConnectionFactory, the AQjmsFactory expects this naming convention!
    .url("jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:SID")
    .credentials("user", "password")
    .contextFactory("oracle.jms.AQjmsInitialContextFactory")
    .listenerCount(1)
    .usePersistentDeliveryMode

// TODO check how to set a timeout on the reply
val jmsScenario = scenario("JMS DSL test")
  .repeat(1) {
    exec(
      jms("req reply testing")
        .reqreply
        .queue("AQ_ADMIN.QUEUE_NAME")
        .textMessage("some message")
        .check(simpleCheck(checkBodyTextCorrect))
    )
}

def checkBodyTextCorrect(m: Message) = {
    // this assumes that the service just does an "uppercase" transform on the text
    m match {
        case tm: TextMessage => tm.getText == "text that should be in the reply message"
        case _ => false
    }
} 

setUp(jmsScenario.inject(atOnceUsers(1)).protocols(jmsConfig));
```

**jndi.properties**

I had to add the jndi.properties to the classpath:

```
db_url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:SID
```

**pom.xml**

Dependencies (maven):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>aqapi</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

"contextFactory" is the class name of your ContextFactory. [Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14257/jm_create.htm) seems to state it's "oracle.jms.AQjmsFactory".

"connectionFactoryName" is the key used for the JNDI look-up. [Doc again](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14257/jm_create.htm) seems to state it's "cn=OracleDBConnections".